# How to mock property source in spring test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I'm writing unit tests for my controller and faced an issue that `desktop.properties` file doesn't exist on my build server and shouldn't exist there.

I have this main SpringBoot class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.xxx")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.xxx")
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:desktop.properties")})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={JmsAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:multipart.xml","classpath:column-maps-config.xml","classpath:model-ui-name-maps-config.xml"})
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware, WebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

This class imports `desktop.properties` as you can notice.

And I have a test class that starts with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SomeControllerTest {
}
```

If I my environment doesn't have the `desktop.properties` file or I simply delete it then tests couldn't be run because `ApplicationConfig` class can't be instantiated without the dependency.

My question is how can I mock `desktop.properties` or create a custom configuration for test purposes in order to replace `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)` with my test context?

Could you be so kind to give me any hints about it?

P.S. the current project is a quite old one with old versions so this is only one way I found to create tests for controllers with minimum changes to `pom.xml`

Comment: if having as little version changes as possible is an important constraint for you then mentioning what these versions are seems substantial to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this test anotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SomeControllerTest {
}
```

Next you have to create specific test desktop.properties in /src/test/resources

Answer (score 5):

The `@TestPropertySource` annotation is the simplest way to configure property source in Spring integration tests.

Comment: This answer really seems like the most fitting response to the given question. The name of the annotation says it all!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different configuration class for test environment and use it in your test.
This test application config class will not have the statement -

@PropertySourcesl(value = {
 @PropertySource("classpath:desktop.propertie         s ")})

And wherever you are using some of the properties from the above file, use some default values so that it won't fail with any runtime exception.